# Como subtrair uma data e hora de outra data e hora no Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic

Necessito pegar duas datas e hora, já definidas no template assim: 
`<ion-datetime name="ent" [(ngModel)]="ent" displayFormat="DD MMM, HH:mm"></ion-datetime>`,
Na classe defini assim: 
`ent:Date=new Date();`
 porém desejo saber se alguém conhece uma forma de subtrair esses valores de forma que, por exemplo, eu consiga ver quanto tempo e dias um carro ficou no estacionamento. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você chegou a ver se em [algumas dessas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+diferen%C3%A7a+datas+) já existe algo que vc precisa? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc pode usar a biblioteca [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```
        var data1 = moment('29/04/2019 00:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var data2 = moment('30/04/2019 02:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var diferenca = data1.diff(data2, 'hours');

        console.log(diferenca); // 2
//
        var data1 = moment('29/04/2019 00:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var data2 = moment('30/04/2019 02:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var diferenca = data1.diff(data2, 'days');

        console.log(diferenca); // 1
```

Comment: Já consegui, utilizei o ```<ion-datatime>``` mesmo que pega o valor em string, armazenei na minha variável da classe por meio de um ```[(ngModel)]``` e depois fiz um botão que chama uma função na classe com o ```(click)="nomeDaFuncao()"```

Comment: Confira como ficou a classe e o projeto completo no meu GitHub: Projeto completo: https://www.github.com/joaopauloexcel/aplicativo-estacionamento
Classe: https://github.com/joaopauloexcel/aplicativo-estacionamento/blob/master/aplicativoEstacionamento/src/app/new-item/new-item.page.ts